# Can you call an earlier version of MSBuild from 2013 from TFS build definition

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs, msbuild, ssas

Our company just migrated our project from a TFS 2012 server to 2013 TFS server as well as our build controllers (2012 servers to 2013). I know within VS2013 MSBuild is now part of the application however I have a need to also reference older build machines that build some of our SSIS and SSAS projects as part of deployment. The challenge I have is these projects use Business Intelligence for 2008R2 and I cannot migrate the solution/projects forward. 
Within my analytic's solution which was authored in VS2010 I have the following build command:

```
 <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <!-- Build SSIS Package-->
    <Exec Command="&quot;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe&quot; &quot;$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..\AnalyticsSSAS\AnalyticsSSAS.dwproj&quot; /Build" />
  </Target>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <PostBuildEvent>xcopy "$(ProjectDir)..\AnalyticsSSAS\bin\*.*"  /y</PostBuildEvent>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

When I try to run a build using the 2013 definition the build fails and states that the msbiuld taks EXEC is not recognized. I can open the solution and projects individually and build them (running 2010) with no issues 2013 wants to migrate the solution to which I can't do.

Here is the actual message generated in the build log file:

```
"f:\blds\26\DevCI\src\Analytics.sln" (default target) (1) ->
   "f:\blds\26\DevCI\src\Database\Dashboards\SSASBuild\SSASBuild.csproj" (default target) (2) ->
   (BeforeBuild target) -> 
     f:\blds\26\DevCI\src\Database\Dashboards\SSASBuild\SSASBuild.csproj(85,5): error MSB3073: The command ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" "f:\blds\26\DevCI\src\Database\Dashboards\SSASBuild\..\AnalyticsSSAS\AnalyticsSSAS.dwproj" /Build" exited with code 1.


   "f:\blds\26\DevCI\src\Analytics.sln" (default target) (1) ->
   "f:\blds\26\DevCI\src\Database\Dashboards\SSISBuild\SSISBuild.csproj" (default target) (3) ->
     f:\blds\26\DevCI\src\Database\Dashboards\SSISBuild\SSISBuild.csproj(84,5): error MSB3073: The command ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" "f:\blds\26\DevCI\src\Database\Dashboards\SSISBuild\..\AnalyticsSSIS\AnalyticsSSIS.dtproj" /Build" exited with code 1.
```

I suspect from what I have read that MSBuild in VS2013 will not allow for a lower version of MSBuild v9.0 to be referenced without migrating the project to a newer version.

Has anyone seen this before and is there any workaround for this type of build?

-cheers

Comment: Seems strange. The exec task hasn't been deprecated and should be available in the [VS 2013 version of MSBuild](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8zx72cd.aspx). Can you post the exact error message you're seeing?

Comment: @JamesReed  I updated the post with the output from the error log. Researching the error code drew me to the conclusion that the EXEC / Build command was not being recognized.

Comment: It looks like the EXEC tasks is working fine, but when devenv tries to build that dwproj it's failing for some reason. If you have access to the build agent try opening the solution in visual studio and try to compile from there. this might give you more information.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are many solution, but the basic idea is to force using the old MSBuild version.

**Custom Build Template** (*old style*)

Add an MSBuild activity and set the ToolPath Property to the old version. You must expose a list of solutions to build as Template arguments.

**Script** (*new style*)

Write a post-build (or pre-build) script that invokes the proper MSBuild version with the path to the solution.